# Deserialize nested ICollection<BaseType> in Asp.Net Web API 2 controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api Controller like this one :

```
public IHttpActionResult Create(PaymentDTO Payment)
```

My DTOs are:

```
public class PaymentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TransactionDTO> Transactions { get; set; }

}

public class TransactionDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string CreateTime { get; set; }
        public string UpdateTime { get; set; }
    }

public class SaleDTO : TransactionDTO
{
        public string Total { get; set; }
        public string Currency{ get; set; }
}

public class OrderDTO : TransactionDTO
{
       public string State {get;set;}
}
```

I receive the following JSON formatted data :

> ```
> {
>   "Type": "sale",
>   "Id": 101,
>   "transactions": [
>     {
>       "Total": "30.50",
>       "Currency": "USD",
>       "Description": "transaction description"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

I want JSON.net to instantiate either a `IEnumerable<SaleDTO>` or `IEnumerable<OrderDTO>` based on the `Type` Property.

I could've used a custom type converter, but only if `Type` property was in `TransactionDTO`. But I want the `Type` property to be in the parent object (`PaymentDTO`)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) on the `PaymentDTO` class:

```
public class PaymentDTOConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(PaymentDTO).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var payment = (PaymentDTO)existingValue ?? new PaymentDTO();

        // Extract the transactions.
        var transactions = obj.Property("transactions") ?? obj.Property("Transactions");
        if (transactions != null)
            transactions.Remove();

        // Populate the remaining regular properties.
        using (var subReader = obj.CreateReader())
            serializer.Populate(subReader, payment);

        if (transactions != null)
        {
            // Deserialize the transactions list.
            var type = PaymentDTO.GetTransactionDTOType(payment.type) ?? typeof(TransactionDTO);
            using (var subReader = transactions.Value.CreateReader())
                // Here we are taking advantage of array covariance.
                payment.Transactions = (IEnumerable<TransactionDTO>)serializer.Deserialize(subReader, type.MakeArrayType());
        }

        return payment;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your `PaymentDTO` class as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PaymentDTOConverter))]
public class PaymentDTO
{
    static Dictionary<string, Type> namesToTransactions;
    static Dictionary<Type, string> transactionsToNames = new Dictionary<Type, string>
    {
        { typeof(SaleDTO), "sale" },
        { typeof(OrderDTO), "order" },
    };

    static PaymentDTO()
    {
        namesToTransactions = transactionsToNames.ToDictionary(p => p.Value, p => p.Key);
    }

    public static string GetTransactionDTOTypeName<TTransactionDTO>() where TTransactionDTO : TransactionDTO
    {
        string name;
        if (transactionsToNames.TryGetValue(typeof(TTransactionDTO), out name))
            return name;
        return null;
    }

    public static Type GetTransactionDTOType(string name)
    {
        Type type;
        if (namesToTransactions.TryGetValue(name, out type))
            return type;
        return null;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("transactions")]
    public IEnumerable<TransactionDTO> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```